# WPF mapping border to Bitmapimage (Not a duplicate)

Tags: c#, wpf

I post this before and it was remove for being a duplicate. It is not. My problem is different then what that other people is doing. He is not doing zoom nor pan, and does not have a boarder.

I am using Stretch="Fill" to place my entire picture in the borders of an Image box. I am using a Border so that I can do Zoom and Pan. I am using the Canvas to draw rectangles around giving click areas. I want to map the left mouse click coordinates of the Canvas with zoom and pan back to the original image. here is my XAML code :

```
        `
          <Border x:Name="VideoPlayerBorder" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray"  >
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasGridScreen"   MouseLeftButtonDown="VideoPlayerSource_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"  >
    <Image x:Name="VideoPlayerSource"  Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"   MouseLeftButtonUp="VideoPlayerSource_OnMouseLeftButtonUp"  MouseWheel="VideoPlayerSource_OnMouseWheel"  MouseMove="VideoPlayerSource_OnMouseMove"  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=CanvasGridScreen}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=CanvasGridScreen}" Stretch="Fill" >
    </Image>
    </Canvas>
```

`

here is my C# code:

```
`private void VideoPlayerSource_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 { 
  VideoPlayerSource.CaptureMouse();
    var tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)VideoPlayerSource.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
    start = e.GetPosition(VideoPlayerBorder);
    origin = new Point(tt.X, tt.Y);
    _stIR = start;
    _stIR2 = start;


    addRemoveItems(sender, e);
}

  
private void addRemoveItems(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // this is the event that will check if we clicked on a rectangle or if we clicked on the canvas
    // if we clicked on a rectangle then it will do the following

    if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
    {
        // if the click source is a rectangle then we will create a new rectangle
        // and link it to the rectangle that sent the click event
        Rectangle activeRec = (Rectangle)e.OriginalSource; // create the link between the sender rectangle

        CanvasGridScreen.Children.Remove(activeRec); // find the rectangle and remove it from the canvas
    }

    // if we clicked on the canvas then we do the following
    else
    {
        // generate a random colour and save it inside the custom brush variable
        Custombrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(1, 255),
        (byte)r.Next(1, 255), (byte)r.Next(1, 233)));

        // create a re rectangle and give it the following properties
        // height and width 50 pixels
        // border thickness 3 pixels, fill colour set to the custom brush created above
        // border colour set to black
        Rectangle newRec = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 50,
            Height = 50,
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            Fill = Custombrush,
            Stroke = Brushes.Black
        };

        // once the rectangle is set we need to give a X and Y position for the new object
        // we will calculate the mouse click location and add it there
        Canvas.SetLeft(newRec, Mouse.GetPosition(CanvasGridScreen).X); // set the left position of rectangle to mouse X
        Canvas.SetTop(newRec, Mouse.GetPosition(CanvasGridScreen).Y); // set the top position of rectangle to mouse Y

        CanvasGridScreen.Children.Add(newRec); // add the new rectangle to the canvas
    }
}

private void VideoPlayerSource_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    TransformGroup transformGroup = (TransformGroup)VideoPlayerSource.RenderTransform;
    ScaleTransform transform = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];

    double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
    double transformScaleX = Math.Round((transform.ScaleX + zoom), 2);
    double transformScaleY = Math.Round((transform.ScaleY + zoom), 2);

    if (transformScaleX <= 8.2 && transformScaleX >= 1)
    {
        transform.ScaleX = Math.Round(transform.ScaleX + zoom, 2);
        transform.ScaleY = Math.Round(transform.ScaleY + zoom, 2);
        zoomFactor2 = zoomFactor2 + zoom;
        zoomFactor = zoomFactor2;
    }
}

void PanMethod(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)VideoPlayerSource.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
    Vector v = start - e.GetPosition(VideoPlayerBorder);


    if (zoomFactor > 1.0)
    {
        tt.X = origin.X - v.X;
        tt.Y = origin.Y - v.Y;
    }
}
```

is there a function that would give me this information ? is there a way of using TransformGroup or ScaleTransform to return the actual location in the picture that was clicked? again the Image with possible zoom and/or pan

Comment: Does this not help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual

Comment: @AustinMcfadden you need to build more reputation on the site in order to do things like vote and mark answers as correct. Besides, that was technically a "comment" and not an "answer".

Comment: I'll put this as an answer to help those landing here with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual

The right way to translate coordinates back to the original pre-transforms control is to use the TransformToVisual helper.  It's probably a good idea to do that regardless since transforms could be applied higher up in the stack.

In your case you want to call:

```
GeneralTransform transform = CanvasGridScreen.TransformToVisual(VideoPlayerSource);
Point normalizedPoint = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```